# Memory leackage in reading the file content

Tags: zig

I've the below code for reading and printing the content of the specified file, this code is working fine:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const contents = try readFile("index.html");
    std.debug.print("File contents: {s}\n", .{contents});
}

pub fn readFile(filename: []const u8) ![]u8 {
    const allocator = std.heap.page_allocator;
    const file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile(filename, .{});
    defer file.close();
    const contents = try file.reader().readAllAlloc(allocator, std.math.maxInt(usize));
  //  defer allocator.free(contents);
    return contents;
}
```

I was wondering why it gave me an error once I tried to clear the memory using `defer allocator.free(contents);` and worked fine once I removed it, do not I need to free the memory allocation?

Comment: What error and where are you getting it?

Comment: @Alejandro I got `File contents: thread 3636 panic: Deadlock detected` with using `defer allocator.free(contents);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`defer`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#defer) works on the block level. `allocator.free(contents)` is called before `readFile` returns, which means the function tries to return and free the memory at the same time. This is simply wrong.

Modify `readFile` to accept an allocator instead and free the memory outside of the function. For example:

```
pub fn main() !void {
    const allocator = std.heap.page_allocator;
    const contents = try readFile(allocator, "index.html");
    defer allocator.free(contents);

    std.debug.print("File contents: {s}\n", .{ contents });
}

pub fn readFile(allocator: std.mem.Allocator, filename: []const u8) ![]u8 {
    const file = try std.fs.cwd().openFile(filename, .{});
    defer file.close();
    const contents = try file.reader().readAllAlloc(allocator, std.math.maxInt(usize));
    return contents;
}
```